# SSH over IPv6 got "Permission denied" error

Tags: ssh, ipv6

I have a server that I can connect via SSH over IPv4 address. Now I want to SSH over IPv6.

I'm sure that my server is assigned with a valid IPv6 address, and I've configured sshd to listen on v6 address (I set it to **[::]:311**), but when I run (on my laptop)

`ssh -v -6 -p 311 PUBLIC_V6_IP -l same_user_as_v4 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

I got the following output:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p2, OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/winus/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to PUBLIC_V6_IP [PUBLIC_V6_IP] port 311.
debug1: connect to address PUBLIC_V6_IP port 311: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host PUBLIC_V6_IP port 311: Permission denied
```

#### Some extra info:

1. My laptop is running Arch Linux, while my server is Ubuntu Server 10.10
2. sshd -V on the server shows `OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`
3. ssh -V on my laptop shows `OpenSSH_5.8p2, OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011`
4. ssh -6 ::1 on my laptop is OK.
5. ping6 PUBLIC_V6_IP is OK.
6. ssh -6 ::1 -p 311 on the server is OK.
7. ssh -6 PUBLIC_V6_IP -p 311 on the server is also OK.

### Question: Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Can you do `strace -o log.txt -e network ssh -6 PUBLIC_V6_IP true`, then check for "`EPERM`" in log.txt?

Comment: @grawity I paste the output [here](https://gist.github.com/971246) - I didn't find EPERM in it...

Comment: Oh, it's EACCESS, not EPERM :( (It's present on the last line.)

Comment: I can't connect to the addres in the link on port 311, and I have otherwise working IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes could be:

- Local firewall (`ip6tables`)
- External firewall on your network (according to some sources, ICMPv6 "Administratively prohibited" error message is interpreted by Linux as EACCESS)
- AppArmor, SELinux, Smack (although neither of them is on by default on Arch)

Things you could try:

- reset ip6tables rules
- connect to the server using other programs (`socat stdio tcp:[2604:....]:311`) and see if they return the same message; test with both same and different ports
- `ping6`, `traceroute6`, and see if any hop returns "Administratively prohibited" or any other error